# Multiplying Two Columns of a gridview and show it in a new column

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

i want to mul two columns of my gridview and show it in a third column. The problem i am facing it shows an error of null reference exception in rowdatabound code..how to fix that?
This in my .cs code

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections;
       using System.Configuration;
       using System.Data;
       using System.Data.SqlClient;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Web;
       using System.Web.Security;
       using System.Web.UI;
       using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
       using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
       using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
       using System.Xml.Linq;
       using System.Globalization;

       public partial class ProjectBilling : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //AppSettingsReader configReader = new AppSettingsReader();

    }

}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        TextBox txtHour = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Hour");
        TextBox txtrate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("RatePerHour");
        TextBox TextBoxInsertTotal = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Total");

        txtHour.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(txtrate.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInsertTotal.ClientID) + "')";
        txtrate.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(txtrate.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInsertTotal.ClientID) + "')";
    }
} 

private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDbConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected double CalculateTotal(double RatePerHour, int Hour)
{
    return RatePerHour * Hour;
}
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Hour"].DefaultValue =
            ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHour")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ProjectType"].DefaultValue =
                        ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlName")).SelectedValue;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["ProjectName"].DefaultValue =
                        ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("projectnameTextBox")).Text;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Month"].DefaultValue =
                       ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlmonth")).SelectedValue;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Year"].DefaultValue =
           ((DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlyear")).SelectedValue;
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["RatePerHour"].DefaultValue =
           ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtrate")).Text;


        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }


}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

}

My aspx code is:(total calculation must change after editing the hour or RatePerHour )

```
               <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="ProjectBilling.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectBilling" %>

              <!DOCTYPE html>

              <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <head runat="server">
             <title>Project Billing</title>
            <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            </head>
       <script>
          function multiplication(hour, rate, TextBoxInsertTotal) {
    //Your logic for multiplication
    var hour = document.getElementById(txtHour).value;
    var rate = document.getElementById(txtrate).value;
    document.getElementById(TextBoxInsertTotal).value = hour * rate;
     }
     </script>
     <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                  <div id="menu">
                      <ul>
                <li><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="ProjectEntry.aspx">Projects</a></li>

                <li><a href="ProjectBilling.aspx">Project Billing</a></li>

                <li><a href="report1.aspx">Report</a></li>

                <li><a href="login.aspx">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <h2>Project Billing</h2>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" align="center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ProjectBillingId" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Id">

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="Add_Click" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Type" SortExpression="Project Type">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNames" runat="server" DataTextField="ProjectType" DataValueField="ProjectType" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectType") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectType") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" runat="server" DataTextField="ProjectType" DataValueField="ProjectType" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Name" SortExpression="Project Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="projectNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectName") %>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="projectnameTextBox" runat="server">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour" SortExpression="Hour">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Hour") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Hour") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHour" runat="server" CssClass="txthr"></asp:TextBox>
                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="FirstName is reqired" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate/Hour" SortExpression="Rate/Hour">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ratePerHourTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RatePerHour") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="hourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RatePerHour") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="FirstName is reqired" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total">
                    <%--<ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="totalLabel" runat="server" CssClass="total" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,("RatePerHour"))%>*<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,("Hour"))%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>--%>
                    <%--<EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEditTotal" runat="server" Text='<%#CalculateTotal((double)Eval("RatePerHour"), (int)Eval("Hour")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>--%>
                     <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxInsertTotal" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Year") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Year:</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2017">2017</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2016">2016</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2015">2015</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2014">2014</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2013">2013</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2012">2012</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2011">2011</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2010">2010</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2009">2009</asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEditYear" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Year is reqired" ControlToValidate="DropDownList3" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Year:"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Year") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyear" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Year:</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2017">2017</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2016">2016</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2015">2015</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2014">2014</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2013">2013</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2012">2012</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2011">2011</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2010">2010</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2009">2009</asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvYear" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Year is reqired" ControlToValidate="ddlyear" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Day:"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month" SortExpression="Month">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Month") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Month:</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="January">January</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="February">February</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="March">March</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="April">April</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="May">May</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="June">June</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="July">July</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="August">August</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="September">September</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="October">October</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="November">November</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="December">December</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEditMonth" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Month is reqired" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Month:"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Month") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmonth" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Month:</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="January">January</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="February">February</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="March">March</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="April">April</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="May">May</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="June">June</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="July">July</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="August">August</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="September">September</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="October">October</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="November">November</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="December">December</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMonth" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Month is reqired" ControlToValidate="ddlmonth" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Month:"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:ProjectManagementConnectionString%>" SelectCommand="SELECT * from Project"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectManagementConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ProjectBilling] WHERE [ProjectBillingId] = @ProjectBillingId" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ProjectBilling] ([Hour],[RatePerHour], [ProjectType],[ProjectName], [Month], [Year]) VALUES (@Hour,@RatePerHour, @ProjectType,@ProjectName, @Month, @Year)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProjectBilling]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ProjectBilling] SET [Hour] = @Hour,[RatePerHour]=@RatePerHour, [ProjectType] = @ProjectType,[ProjectName] = @ProjectName, [Month] = @Month, [Year] = @Year WHERE [ProjectBillingId] = @ProjectBillingId">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectBillingId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Hour" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RatePerHour" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectType" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Month" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Hour" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RatePerHour" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectType" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Month" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectBillingId" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />

    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried several options in javascript inside my code..None works..a sample code will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you add break point to tell us which line is throwing `NullReferenceException` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here is with your control's ID in the aspx page. For instance, you have the below text box in asp grid view row:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Hour") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Text box ID here is 'TextBox1', but in the code behind you are searching for text box with ID 'Hour'

```
TextBox txtHour = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Hour");
```

I think you have mistaken the TextBox Id to the asp:TemplateField header attribute

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour" SortExpression="Hour">
```

**Ensure the ID with which you search in the code behind (using *FindControl*) is the same as the control'd ID in the aspx page** (Text box control ID here)

As the FindControl method(in RowDataBound event) in the code behind is not able to find a TextBox control with ID 'Hour' it is throwing the error 'null reference exception'

Same goes with other control in your Grid Row.

**UDPATED ANSWER**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                TextBox txtHour = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtHour");
                TextBox txtrate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ratePerHourTextBox");
                TextBox TextBoxInsertTotal = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxInsertTotal");

                txtHour.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(txtrate.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInsertTotal.ClientID) + "')";
                txtrate.Attributes["onKeyup"] = "javascript: return multiplication('" + Convert.ToInt32(txtHour.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(txtrate.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxInsertTotal.ClientID) + "')";


            }
        }
```

Comment: in this context give FintControl("TextBox1") as you have named the text box under Hour template as "TextBox1". Do the same correction for other find control used.

Comment: did u the same change for other controls that you are trying to find in the code behind? Check if the parameter that you pass in the FindControl("") method is same as the ID of the control (Text Box here). Do this for RatePerHour and total textbox.

Comment: You need to change the ID's in the Grid also. "TextBox1" to "Hour" or what your preferred ID is

Comment: @Lysgaard he does not have to change since the ID in aspx is 'TextBox1' and the FindControl searches with the same and I think he has not updated the code here

Comment: Ok - as long as the ID's matches what he is looking for everything should work :-)

Comment: @star-tasneem Could you please post your present code? So we can see your changes.

Comment: replace your GridView1_RowDataBound code with the one i have added to my answer now under UPDATE ANSWER

Comment: @star_tasneem can you tell me the IDs of all the text boxes you are trying  to access ( or get it thri FindControl) in GridView1_RowDataBound method?

Comment: in my footerTemplate i insert in hour field of textbox id=txtHour and rate/hour field of textbox id=txtRate..and want to show the mul result in a new column of the fiel total of textbox id=TextBoxInsertTotal

Comment: can you please confirm the error you are getting after replacing you code with mine in the answer? becus it shud be able to find the text box.

Comment: i put a breakepoint in rowdatabound..it shows me txtHour,txtrate,TextBoxInsertTotal has null value..and when the FindControl statement is tried to be executed it shows nullreference exception

Comment: Please explain to me: You have two textboxes regarding "Hour": TextBox1 and txtHour. The txtHour is in the footer and will only be found when the RowDataBound is able to iterate through the whole Grid. Are you sure that it isn't the TextBox1 you want to evaluate?

Comment: @star_tasneem can you replace 'if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)' with 'if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)' in the method GridView1_RowDataBound and check if it works? ( i have edited this is my answer too under the Updated Answer)

Comment: @Lysgaard: I think only when the row type is footer it gets in to the if block to find control in the row databound method

Comment: @ user3240361 You are right - but if so your solution wrong: This line: TextBox txtHour = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtHour"); will never find anything. Because "txtHour" is a textbox in the footer. It should if his code is not changed be "TextBox1"

Comment: I had changed my code to reflect 'Footer' in the place of 'DataRow' in the if condition

Comment: I rest my case for this one - it is dfficult with no updated code from star_tasneem - good luck with the troubleshooting. :-)

Comment: @star_tasneem do you have any updates on this issue?

Comment: thnx @user3240361 it works perfect..but the issue is how to operate when i click the edit option in the gridview..Will the logic change??

Comment: @star_tasneem if you want to hav it in the edit row event then create a new edit template in the grid view aspx column and add an control that you wanted to show while row is in edit mode

Answer (score 0):

When you try to find a control (or several controls) you should use the ID

```
TextBox txtHour = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Hour");
```

You are trying to find a control with the ID "Hour". That is not existing. It is in your code called "TextBox1"

```
This line:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Hour")%>'>
Should be changed to this:
<asp:TextBox ID="Hour" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Hour")%>'>
```

Try to find it by using the right ID - in this case "TextBox1"

As I see it none of these controls are present in your grid:

```
TextBox txtHour = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Hour");
TextBox txtrate = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("RatePerHour");
TextBox TextBoxInsertTotal = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Total");
```

Comment: what would be the correction..plz reply..show it in code

Comment: The important thing is that your textbox ID's matches what you are looking for in your eventhandler. If ID = "Hour" then you should search for "Hour" in your event handler. You will never find "strHour" for example. Ok?